# Main Destination for Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, europe, schengen-visas, applications

Planning a eurotrip from India this summer...iten:
Entry: Amsterdam 3 nights
Belgium:4 nights
Italy: 5 nights
Spain: 5 nights
France: 3 nights port of exit back to India.

Which consulate should I apply my visa for this itinerary?

Comment: I believe you should apply for the country that you will spend more time. In this case: Italy or Spain.

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92625/can-i-apply-to-france-for-a-schengen-visa-when-id-be-there-a-half-day-more-than

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Least Strict Schengen Visa Application? - France or Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43258/least-strict-schengen-visa-application-france-or-italy)

Comment: If there are two (or more) equally most-important countries, then you are to apply to country-of-entry, EVEN IF that is the least-important country.

Answer (score 2):

According to a few resources mentioned below, and the information the Netherland Embassy had given to me a while ago, the country (embassy) you're applying your visa from, has to be either the first country you're entering within the Schengen zone, or the one that you'll be staying the longest.

You can then travel within the Schengen area to other countries. Which consulate you should apply your visa would probably depend on how long you're going to stay in each country, what flights/buses/trains you're going to take and which itinerary is the most efficient/cheapest. etc.

There have been other questions previously asked ([Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)) which I highly recommend to search and read before posting new questions.

You can also read the [FAQs](https://eeas.europa.eu/sites/eeas/files/frequently_asked_questions_en.pdf) about the visas and also [this info](https://ie.ambafrance.org/France-must-be-your-Main-destination-country-Is-the-French-embassy-the-correcthttps://ie.ambafrance.org/France-must-be-your-Main-destination-country-Is-the-French-embassy-the-correct) from the French embassy about choosing the main destination correctly.

P.S. Based on what I've heard from friends, NL is fairly straightforward, efficient, and easy on issuing visas.

Comment: Your first link is to schengenvisainfo.com, which is a private website whose goal is to sell ads, and which is infamous for providing misleading or outdated information in their quest to get viewers for their ads.

Comment: In particular, the page you're linking to completely ignores the _main rule_ that one must apply to the country where the **main purpose** of the trip is located. _Only_ for trips where there is no clearly located main purpose will the fallback rules about counting length-of-stay apply.

Comment: Amendments made. Thanks for the warning.